# Powershell - How to get all characters to the right of nth character?

Tags: powershell

How do you get all of the characters to the right of nth character?  In this case, I'd like all characters to the right of the 6th character.

**STRING:**

- 111111_outputfile-9999999
- 222222SMITHOUTDOORSINC_SMITH

**DESIRED RESULTS:**

- _outputfile-9999999
- SMITHOUTDOORSINC_SMITH

**POWERSHELL SCRIPT:**

```
$string1 = '111111_outputfile-9999999'
$string2 = '222222SMITHOUTDOORSINC_SMITH'

$result1 = $string1.Substring(6,25)
write-host $result1
$result2 = $string2.Substring(6,30)
write-host $result2
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove the extra number: `$string1.Substring(6); $string2.Substring(6)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) isn't coming back to post his crucial pointer, given in a comment, as an answer:

To get *all remaining* characters - however many - after a given (`0`-based) character position (index), simply *omit* the `length` parameter of the  [`System.String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Substring) method:

```sh
# Get the character at index 1 *and all remaining ones*
'foo'.Substring(1) # -> 'oo'
```

Unfortunately, the `.Substring()` method is quite picky and throws an exception if the character index falls outside the string and/or, with an explicitly specified `length` argument, the implied end point lies beyond the string's actual end.

Typically, you simply want to *default to the empty string* or *get as many characters as are available* in these cases rather than having to deal with exception handling.

To that end, you can use [*regexes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) in combination with the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```sh
# Non-exception-throwing alternative to .Substring(0, 3)
# Extracts *up to* 3 characters.
'12', '1234' -replace '^(.{0,3}).*', '$1' # -> '12', '123'

# Non-exception-throwing alternative to .Substring(2, 2)
# Extracts *up to* 2 characters at index 2, *if any*.
# -> '', '', '3', '34', '34'
'1', '12', '123', '1234', '12345' -replace '^.{0,2}' -replace '^(.{0,2}).*', '$1'
```